Finding conditional density of uniform sample given min and max
Suppose $X_i \sim Unif(0, \theta)$ iid, $i = 1, \dots , n$.
I want to find the conditional density $f(x_1 , \dots , x_n | X_{(1)} = s, X_{(n)} = t)$ where $X_{(1)} = \min \{ X_1 , \dots , X_n \}$ and $X_{(n)} = \max \{ X_1 , \dots , X_n \}$.
I know $(X_{(1)}, X_{(n)})$ has joint pdf $f_T(s, t) = n(n-1)(t-s)^{n-2}\frac{1}{\theta^n}$.
We have $f(x_1 , \dots , x_n | X_{(1)} = s, X_{(n)} = t) = \frac{f(x_1, \dots , x_n, s, t)}{f_T(s,t)}$ where the numerator is joint pdf of the sample, the min and the max.
If the entire sample is greater than $s$ and less than $t$, then one of the $X_i$ is the minimum and one is the maximum. So I have $2 {n \choose 2} = \frac{n!}{(n-2)!} = n(n-1)$ ways to specify which one is which, and the numerator is $n(n-1)\frac{1}{\theta^n}$ when $s \leq x_i \leq t$ for all $i$, and $0$ otherwise. So we have:
$f(x_1 , \dots , x_n | X_{(1)} = s, X_{(n)} = t) = \frac{n(n-1)\frac{1}{\theta^n}}{n(n-1)(t-s)^{n-2}\frac{1}{\theta^n}} = \frac{1}{(t-s)^{n-2}}$
for $s \leq x_1 , \dots , x_n \leq t$.
Is this the correct way to go about this? I have a hard time making/understanding these types of arguments in the continuous case.

Hi Bastiza, I managed to get to a nicer expression for the conditional CDF so I edited my answer. Also I left out the case in which some of the $x_i$ is equal to $s$, simply because it must be treated separately I believe. If you are interested I can include that case in the answer. Also feel free to ask any questions! I'll be glad to help you with this one

Also, I misread the question: our variables are uniform in $[0,\theta]$, not in $[0,1]$. So I edited my answer accordingly

The joint distribution $(X_1,\dots,X_n,X_{(1)}, X_{(n)})$ is not absolutely continuous. As a result  the joint density function does not exist.
We want to compute the conditional CDF $$p_n(x,s,t):=\mathbb P(X_1\le x_1,\dots,X_n\le x_n\mid X_{(1)}=s,X_{(n)}=t),$$ for all $x_1,\dots,x_n,s,t\in[0,\theta]$.
Note that
\begin{align}p_n(x,s,s)&=\mathbb P(X_1\le x_1,\dots,X_n\le x_n\mid X_{(1)}=X_{(n)}=s)\\ &=\mathbb P(s\le x_1,\dots,s\le x_n\mid X_{(1)}=X_{(n)}=s)\\ &=\mathcal I\{s\le x_1,\dots,s\le x_n\}\\ &=\mathcal I\{s \le x_{(1)}\},
\end{align}
for all $x_1,\dots,x_n,s\in[0,\theta]$.
It is also straightforward that $p_n(x,s,t) = 0$ for all $x_1,\dots,x_n,s,t\in[0,\theta]$ with $s>t$.
Consider the more interesting case in which $s < t$. Note that $p_n(x,s,t) = 0$ if $x_{(1)}<s$ or if $x_{(n)}<t$. We will leave out the case in which $s = x_{(1)}$.
From here on we assume that $x_1,\dots,x_n,s,t\in[0,\theta]$ with $s<t$, $\,s<x_{(1)}$ and $t\le x_{(n)}$.
In order to make progress in the computation of $p_n(x,s,t)$ we need to condition on the indexes $A$ and $B$ of the components corresponding to the minimum and the maximum value respectively. So we use law of total probability.
\begin{align} p_n(x,s,t) &=\mathbb P(X_1\le x_1,\dots,X_n\le x_n\mid X_A=s,X_B=t)\\ 
&= \sum_{a\neq b}\Bigl[\mathbb P(A=a,B=b\mid X_A=s,X_B=t)\\&\cdot \mathbb P(X_1\le x_1,\dots,X_n\le x_n\mid X_A=s,X_B=t,A=a,B=b)\Bigr]
\end{align}
Let's focus on the first factor. Knowing the values attained by the minimum and the maximum does not convey any information about the indexes of the components corresponding to the minimum and the maximum. Hence we get
$$\mathbb P(A=a,B=b\mid X_A=s,X_B=t)=\mathbb P(A=a,B=b)\\=\frac{1}{n(n-1)}.$$
Let's focus on the second factor. Factoring out non-random events, we get
\begin{align}
&\phantom{=}\mathbb P(X_1\le x_1,\dots,X_n\le x_n\mid X_A=s,X_B=t,A=a,B=b)\\
&=\mathbb P\Bigl(\bigcap_i\{X_i\le x_i\}\mid X_A=s,X_B=t,A=a,B=b\Bigr)\\
&=\mathbb P\Bigl(\{X_a\le x_a\}\cap\{X_b\le x_b\}\cap\bigcap_{i\neq a,b}\{X_i\le x_i\}\mid X_A=s,X_B=t,A=a,B=b\Bigr)\\
&=\mathbb P\Bigl(\{s\le x_a\}\cap\{t\le x_b\}\cap\bigcap_{i\neq a,b}\{X_i\le x_i\}\mid X_A=s,X_B=t,A=a,B=b\Bigr)\\
&=\mathcal I\{s\le x_a\}\,\mathcal I\{t\le x_b\}\,\mathbb P\Bigl(\bigcap_{i\neq a,b}\{X_i\le x_i\}\mid X_A=s,X_B=t,A=a,B=b\Bigr)\\
&=\mathcal I\{s\le x_a\}\,\mathcal I\{t\le x_b\}\,\mathbb P\Bigl(\bigcap_{i\neq a,b}\{X_i\le x_i\}\mid X_A=s,X_B=t\Bigr).
\end{align}
The last equality follows from the fact that knowing the values of the indexes $A,B$ does not convey any information about the values of the remaining $X_i$.
On the other hand, knowing the minimum and the maximum value does convey information about the values of the remaining $X_i$. In fact, conditional on $X_A=s,X_B=t$, the remaining $X_i$ are $\mathrm{Unif}(s,t)$ iid distributed. Hence we get
\begin{align}
&\mathcal I\{s\le x_a\}\,\mathcal I\{t\le x_b\}\,\mathbb P\Bigl(\bigcap_{i\neq a,b}\{X_i\le x_i\}\mid X_A=s,X_B=t\Bigr)\\ &=\mathcal I\{s\le x_a\}\,\mathcal I\{t\le x_b\}\prod_{i\neq a,b} \biggl(\frac{\min\{x_i,t\} - s}{t-s}\biggr)\\
&=\mathcal I\{s\le x_a\}\,\mathcal I\{t\le x_b\}\,\frac{(t-s)^2}{\bigl(\min\{x_a,t\} - s\bigr)\bigl(\min\{x_b,t\} - s\bigr)}\prod_{i=1}^n \biggl(\frac{\min\{x_i,t\} - s}{t-s}\biggr)\\
&=\mathcal I\{s\le x_a\}\,\mathcal I\{t\le x_b\}\,\frac{t-s}{\min\{x_a,t\} - s}\prod_{i=1}^n \biggl(\frac{\min\{x_i,t\} - s}{t-s}\biggr).
\end{align}
Putting everything back we get
\begin{align}
p_n(x,s,t) &= \\
&= \sum_{a\neq b}\Bigl[\mathbb P(A=a,B=b\mid X_A=s,X_B=t)\\&\cdot \mathbb P(X_1\le x_1,\dots,X_n\le x_n\mid X_A=s,X_B=t,A=a,B=b)\Bigr]\\
&=\sum_{a\neq b}\Biggl[\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\mathcal I\{s\le x_a\}\,\mathcal I\{t\le x_b\}\,\frac{t-s}{\min\{x_a,t\} - s}\prod_{i=1}^n \biggl(\frac{\min\{x_i,t\} - s}{t-s}\biggr)\Biggr]
\\
&=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n (\min\{x_i,t\} - s)}{n(n-1)(t-s)^{n}}\sum_{a\neq b}\mathcal I\{s\le x_a\}\,\mathcal I\{t\le x_b\}\,\frac{t-s}{\min\{x_a,t\} - s}\\
&=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n (\min\{x_i,t\} - s)}{n(n-1)(t-s)^{n}}\sum_{a\neq b}\mathcal I\{t\le x_b\}\,\frac{t-s}{\min\{x_a,t\} - s}.
\end{align}
In the last equality the term $\mathcal I\{s\le x_a\}$ was removed because we assumed that $s< x_{(1)}$. Let's expand the sum.
\begin{align}
\sum_{a\neq b}\mathcal I\{t\le x_b\}\,\frac{t-s}{\min\{x_a,t\} - s} &= \sum_{b=1}^n I\{t\le x_b\}\sum_{a\neq b}\frac{t-s}{\min\{x_a,t\} - s}\\
&= \sum_{b=1}^n I\{t\le x_b\}\biggl(\sum_{a=1}^n\frac{t-s}{\min\{x_a,t\} - s}- \frac{t-s}{\min\{x_b,t\} - s}\biggr)\\
&= \sum_{b=1}^n I\{t\le x_b\}\biggl(\sum_{a=1}^n\frac{t-s}{\min\{x_a,t\} - s}- \frac{t-s}{t - s}\biggr)\\
&= \biggl(\sum_{i=1}^n I\{t\le x_i\}\biggr)\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{t-s}{\min\{x_i,t\} - s}-1\biggr)
\end{align}
Finally we get the conditional cdf
\begin{align}
&\mathbb P(X_1\le x_1,\dots,X_n\le x_n\mid X_{(1)}=s,X_{(n)}=t)\\
&=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n (\min\{x_i,t\} - s)}{n(n-1)(t-s)^{n}}\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^n I\{t\le x_i\}\biggr)\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{t-s}{\min\{x_i,t\} - s}-1\biggr),
\end{align}
for all $x_1,\dots,x_n,s,t\in[0,\theta]$ with $s < t$, $\,s < x_{(1)}$ and $t\le x_{(n)}$.

There is a small inaccuracy, the expression is also valid when $s=x(1)$. If, for example, $x_1=s, x_2=(s+t)/2, x_3=t $ then $\mathbb P=1/2$.

The last formula here is not valid when $s=x_{(1)}$ because we have zero in the denominator since  $\min{x_{(1)},t}-s=0$

No problem. When multiplying, these factors cancel out. Note that if, in the previous case, $x_1=s+\epsilon$ then $\mathbb P=1/2+\epsilon$, and the cdf is continuous on the right. The value at $x_1=s$ cannot be zero, as you seem to suggest in your formula.

Applying the formula and calling $y_i=\frac{\min(x_i,t)-s}{t-s}$, I obtain the following expression, which I do not know if it coincides with framago's.
\begin{gather*}
\mathbb P(X_1\le x_1,\dots,X_n\le x_n\mid X_{(1)}=s,X_{(n)}=t) =\sum_{i<j}\frac{I(y_i=1)+I(y_j=1)}{n(n-1)y_iy_j}\prod_k y_k
\end{gather*}
